# Are nested angular component folder structures an anti-pattern?

Tags: angularjs

I've noticed that the new Angular router discourages nesting components in folder structure. e.g.

components/
../user/
../../list
../../details

Rather it encourages the simple flat structure of:

components/
../user/
../user-list
../user-details

Is there a reason for this? I've been trying to work my way around getting the first structure to work, so that things could be more "organized" but I'm starting to think there must be a reason why the new router was designed this way.

Comment: are you talking about ngRoute or ui-router?

Comment: Neither: https://angular.github.io/router/